# Pass child data to parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I would like to pass data from a child component to the parent.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/018488478p

In my child component I have this `const = priceShown` that I would like to display in the parent component. As so:

`<h2>Price:{priceShown}</h2>`

I have tried placing functions in the parent then passing them as a props to the child so I can have access to `const = priceShown` as it will live in the parent but `i` comes up as undefined. Here is that code: https://codesandbox.io/s/14vyy31nlj

Comment: Why? Data and props are supposed to flow downwards. If you want a data relationship between a child and parent, handle it in the parent then pass it down to the child.

Comment: You most likely want to [lift the state up to the first common ancestor](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) instead of trying to send data from the child to the parent.

Comment: Yeah I understand thats what I also tried to do but I get an error with one the function I try to pass as a props as shown here: https://codesandbox.io/s/14vyy31nlj

Comment: `i` is not defined in that link. Maybe you wanted to bind it to something else?

Comment: yeah I dont get why its not defined when its in the parent but when in the child it works perfectly fine. So I'm stuck on what to do. How else can I pass it if not on the bind also as its passed in the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead keep the state in the parent and pass down a function as prop that will be called from the child component with the appropriate arguments that will update this state in the parent.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    evenSelected: null
  };

  handleSelectL1 = i => {
    this.setState({
      evenSelected: i,
      oldSelected: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    const product = [
      {
        name: "one",
        price: 1
      },
      {
        name: "two",
        price: 2
      },
      ,
      {
        name: "three",
        price: 3
      }
    ];

    const evenIndex = this.state.evenSelected;

    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          product={product}
          handleSelectL1={this.handleSelectL1}
          evenIndex={evenIndex}
        />
        <h2>Price: </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { product, evenIndex } = this.props;

    const priceShown = product[evenIndex] && product[evenIndex].price;

    return (
      <div>
        {product.map((p, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={p.id}
              className={evenIndex === i ? "selectedRBox" : "selectorRBox"}
              onClick={() => this.props.handleSelectL1(i)}
            >
              <h1 className="selectorTextL">
                {p.name} {evenIndex === i && "selected!"}
              </h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Oh Thank you @Tholle !! You always have the solutions! I hope with time I get as good as you.

Answer (score 1):

In react, the data flow is unidirectional i.e from parent to child.
If Parent Component wants to access Child Component data, you can use refs (though it's not recommended).

Eg:
Lets say you have a function getPrice() defined in your Child component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.getPrice = this.getPrice.bind(this);
};

getPrice() {
    let price = this.refs.child.getPrice();
};

render() {
    return(
        <Child
          ref="child"
        />
    )
  };
}
```

And in your Child component,

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        price: "100"
    }
this.getPrice = this.getPrice.bind(this);
};

getPrice() {
    return this.state.price
  };   
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Vasuki Dileep this also helped awesome!